# Getting data from JSON file based on PHP generated list

Tags: javascript, php, json

It might be a really simple question, but i'm kinda stuck on this one.
I'm creating an image gallery that needs to be described. What I've created a JSON file with data (it contains mostly details about specific images) - images.json, that looks pretty much like this:

```
{
  "Image Name": {
    "position": "horizontal",
    "name": "Image Name",
    "catalog": "{Landscapes}",
    "position": 1,
    "colors": [
      "Beige", 
      "Red"
    ],
    "type": "Landscape",
    "alt": "This is an alternative description for this image"
  },

  ...
```

Then, I've created a simple php file which listed all of the images from a certain FTP folder, so that I can see which of the images has already been uploaded:

```
<?php
$dirname = "images/landscapes/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");

foreach($images as $image) {
echo '<li>
<img alt="<!-- "alt" placeholder -->" data-src="'.$image.'">
<span><!-- "colors" value placeholder --></span>
<span><!-- "type" value placeholder --></span>
<span><!-- "alt" value placeholder --></span>
</li>';

}
?>
```

This is where i got stuck: I know how to generate an unordered list out of JSON file, but what i do want to get is loop through the list of images i've generated on document load and see if that image name is on my JSON list. If $image matches an object in my JSON, the data should be echoed in the placeholders.

No clue how to achieve it, thank you in advance for any tips and help.

Comment: i would recommend adding a `imageUrl` key in that json file, so that it will make easier for displaying and to check the image is exist or not. But in your case you need to fetch the json data and loop through it and compare the image name.

Comment: I think you can use array_intersect() here. You can take an array of images from your JSON. Then create another array of images file names from your glob (foreach loop). The intersect of those two arrays will be the matches you want. There is a function called basename() that will give you the file image filename without the extension.

Comment: @dudeman - that's true, i'm already using basename($image, '.jpg') to get the name, but still don't know how to loop it. The problem is that the JSON database is quite large (around 30mb of data and might be bigger), so looping through it might be inefficient. Maybe there's another solution? Sorry for the non-tech description - i would like to make it this way:

foreach $image check the json file if there's a match,
if yes then echo the data into placeholders. 

Is it possible in any way?

Comment: @Ravager, I assumed that you are already reading in the images.json file and parsing it into a PHP structure ( $images = json_decode(json_string, true) 
 returning a php associative array )? If so, yes, it's a large structure and is not ideal to read in a 30MB file. Consider using a database at this time. Hoever, if "Image Name" is the same as the file name the expense of determining if a file is in the JSON is an inexpensive operation consisting of $images['filename'].